# What is the meaning of “Vediamo chi la spunta questa volta”

Tags: meaning, translation, idioms

This phrase appears early in *L'amica Geniale*.  I take it to mean something like let's see who comes out on top this time or who breaks first this time, but I'm mainly just guessing from context.

Dictionaries tell me that *spuntare* by itself can mean break the point off or appear or make a check mark, but the use here seems idiomatic.

What's a reasonable English translation?

Comment: Welcome on ItalianSE!!

Comment: Grazie, ma dev'essere: Welcome _to_ ItalianSE!!  Le preposizioni sono una grande seccatura, no?

Answer (score 6):

The meaning of *[spuntare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/spuntare1/)* you’re looking for is the following:

> 2. fig. a. Superare, vincere (forse dall’antico sign. marin. di doppiare, superare una punta, un promontorio): *s. una difficoltà, un
>      ostacolo.* Più **spesso assol., con il compl. indeterminato la, avere
>      la meglio, averla vinta**; conseguire, ottenere ciò che ci si
>      proponeva superando ostacoli e difficoltà: *la sua famiglia era
>      contraria a quel matrimonio, ma lei alla fine l’ha spuntata; questa
>      volta non la spunti, neppure se piangi per un mese!; finirono per
>      spuntarla, riebbero quanto percepivano fino a due mesi prima
>      (Pratolini).* Quindi, s. l’impegno, riuscire nel proprio scopo:
>      *animando il cugino a persister nell’impresa, a spuntar l’impegno*
>      (Manzoni).

It means (figuratively) to win, to get your own way.

The phrase you asked could be translated like this:

> Let’s see who gets her own way this time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the definition. By the way, the correct English for your translation is: Let's see who gets _his_ own way this time. Or _her_, in this case, since it's a woman talking about another woman

Comment: @user1236910 Thanks, I corrected the phrase.